# Two Entity Managers in Spring Appliation (Arrango and JPA)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using two Spring Entity manager, Arrango and JPA for my application.

```
@EnableSwagger2
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.xyz.abc")
@EnableArangoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.xyz.abc"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.xyz.abc"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.xyz.abc")
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableProcessApplication
```

As can be seen, I am Enabling repository access. Now when I run my application, I get the following error.

```
The bean 'XYZRepository', defined in com.xyz.abc.core.data.repository.XYZRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on MYControllerAPP, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in com.xyz.abc.core.data.repository.XYZRepository defined in @EnableArangoRepositories declared on MyControllerAPP and overriding is disabled.

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

When I add overriding bean definition to my application.yml file.
The error changes to:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'qualityService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'master'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'masterDataRepository' defined in com.xyz.abc.core.data.repository.MasterDataRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on QualityControllerApp: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.xyz.abc.core.data.model.MasterData
```

this is my MasterDataRepository Interface:

```
 interface MasterDataRepository extends ArangoRepository<MasterData, String>
    {
//Hibernate
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the base problem with:

```
@EnableArangoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.xyz.abc"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.xyz.abc"})
```

You should to set different packages to different repository providers. You won't be able to use one Entity class with different repositories. Try to separate `ArangoRepository` entities and `JpaRepository` entities.